# I don't want error message as "The field <field> must be a date", if I am selecting date in "yyyy/MM/dd" format in en-AU locale

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In model I am using below code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(InformationResources))]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateInvalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(InformationResources))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [FutureDate(ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateInPast", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(InformationResources))]
    public DateTime? FirstTrade { get; set; }
```

In view I am using below code:

```
<div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstTrade, new { @Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.FirstTrade).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),@class = "form-control input-sm", @type = "date", @max = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstTrade)
    </div>
```

Now if I select data from date time picker in "yyyy/MM/dd" format then I am getting error message as "The field FirstTrade must be a date". One more thing that I am using en-Au locale.
Please let me know how to remove the error message If i choose date in "yyyy/MM/dd" format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a custom datepicker or the one rendered by the browser?

Comment: Yes. I m using custome date time picker

Comment: Which one. How have set the datepicker date format?

Comment: Yes I am setting date format there but also proper validation is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the format you like when displaying the date value.

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstTrade, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", new { @Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.FirstTrade).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),@class = "form-control input-sm", @type = "date", @max = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

This is how my model and view look like:

Model:

```
public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Incorporation date")]
        public DateTime? IncorporationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Capital payment date")]
        public DateTime? CapitalPaymentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncorporationDate)
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IncorporationDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "span3 date", @data_date_format = "dd.mm.yyyy", @placeholder = "Incorporation date" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CapitalPaymentDate)
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CapitalPaymentDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "span3 date", @data_date_format = "dd.mm.yyyy", @placeholder = "Capital payment date" })
        </div>
```

**Edit:**

Try setting the globalization tag under system.web to the culture you need:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="nb-NO" culture="nb-NO"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I have already tried with this, It is not working. Please let me know any another solution.

Comment: I've had the same problem and my solution worked. Have you tried using my solution and removing the DisplayFormat attribute from your model? And what version of MVC you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have removed the display formet from model but now after selecting the date from date time picker I am getting error message as " Please enter a value greater than or equal to 0.".Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: What datepicker are you using?

Comment: I m using jquery datetimepicker

Comment: I am also doing the same way but getting error message "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 0."

Comment: @Raj Hm, that's really strange. The last resort solution is to make the field String and implement custom validator for it

Comment: Thanks for your try. Atleast u tried to give the answer. If u have any other solution please let me know.

Comment: In my project I'm suing datepicker from bootstrap, may be you can try using it instead of jq datepicker

Comment: @Raj I've forgotten about web.config change that I've made, try to add your culture in the globalization tag, I've updated the answer with my code

Comment: can you please give me your facebook Id so that I can ask you from there. We cannt extend discussion here more.