# ASP.NET MVC5 display date in custom format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, tostring

I'm trying to format a DateTime Variable so that it's being displayed as `MMMM dd, yyyy`, e.g. June 10, 2011.

In my view I have:

```
@Html.Raw(modelItem => item.MyDateTimeProperty.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

Which throws me an exception as follows:

```
lambda expression cannot be converted to 'string' because 'string' is not
a delegate type
```

Of course, the `item.MyDateTimeProperty` data type is `DateTime`.

For reference I used the following example [1]

```
// The example displays the following output: 
//    Today is June 10, 2011. 
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I see that `stack247`'s answer is the most proper solution in an ideal environment. In my case, however, the controller returns an object which doesn't exist in my model classes. This is due I'm consuming an API to get the data. That's why `Anrei`'s solution is best for me.

```
@Html.Raw(item.MyDateTimeProperty.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548816/mvc-4-date-culture-issue) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Raw` actually expects a string as a parameter, and you are passing in a lambda. Not sure why though, you are not using lambda in any way here. So this is what error message is referring to.

Look like it should be just

```
@Html.Raw(item.MyDateTimeProperty.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can format date time in your View by adding annotation to your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}")]
public DateTime ThisDate { get; set }
```

Then in your View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ThisDate)
```

Comment: This actually is better practice. You should always have everything you need to display as it is on the view by having your model ready/configured for just displaying what you need to display on the view without any logic in the view. The view should just display the data and nothing else. The model does all the necessary work

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Raw()` method accepts a string, I think you should use `@Html.DisplayFor()` instead.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
```

You can also check this question for info on applying formats [I don't want error message as "The field <field> must be a date", if I am selecting date in "yyyy/MM/dd" format in en-AU locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924289/i-dont-want-error-message-as-the-field-field-must-be-a-date-if-i-am-select)